# JPA version conflict with JBoss on Openshift for a Spring application

Tags: spring, jpa, jboss7.x, openshift, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to deploy my Spring application on OpenShift, which uses JBoss Application Server 7.
When deploying, I got the following exception:

```
2015/03/02 06:09:19,941 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.rguidoux.procraft.users.UserDao fr.rguidoux.procraft.home.HomeController.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) [spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
```

After invastigating on the Internet, it seems that the following part of this exception comes from conflicting JPA versions: JPA 2.0 is loaded by JBoss by default, and Hibernate 4.3 uses and imports JPA 2.1.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
```

And indeed, I can see 2 JPA versions in the repository:

```
[MY_APP-MY_NS.rhcloud.com persistence]\> pwd
/var/lib/openshift/MY_ID/app-deployments/current/build-dependencies/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence
[MY_APP-MY_NS.rhcloud.com persistence]\> ls -l
total 0
drwx------. 4 MY_ID MY_ID 42 Mar  2 05:18 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
drwx------. 3 MY_ID MY_ID 24 Mar  1 15:27 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
```

So I have tried to disable JBoss' JPA 2.0 loading by:

-Disabling `<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>` in `.openshift/config/standalone.xml`

-Excluding JPA 2.0 in spring-data-jpa in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

-Adding file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and the deploy still fails.

So my question is: how to use Hibernate 4.3.x (and JPA 2.1) with JBoss on Openshift?

**For information**, I do not use a persistence.xml file but I have the following config in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${dbprocraft.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${dbprocraft.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${dbprocraft.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="fr.rguidoux.procraft" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

**Note:** In Intellij I am using Glassfish instead of JBoss and there is no problem.
I cannot test JBoss in Intellij since I do no see how to add a non-Glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Look at a workaround in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/404223